# I created a resource but files inside it are shown as not existing

Tags: c#

I embedded my files as resource in my C# program. Now i am trying to see that files exist or not through

```
      if(File.Exists(path))
```

but it is not going inside the if block when even the path is the valid path to the files inside the resources. The files are the DTDs, which would be embedded as resources inside the assembly at compile time, and resolved as resources at runtime. Please help. what could possibly the reason? and what am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access your resources in c#, you should use the Properties.Resources class.

For example:

```
string data = Properties.Resources.dtd
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have embedded the resource the file(or Resource) gets embedded in the assembly manifest. You may have to pick up the file as a resource stream from the manifest.

```
string filePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name+"." + resourceFileName; 
Stream fileStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(filePath);
```

Comment: how do i use fileStream? i want to validate my xhtml files against the dtd.

Answer (score 0):

`File.Exists()` is only for the file system. You should be able to reach your file by using

```
myProject.Properties.Resources.Image01;
```

And there's no real reason to check if the file exists.